# GraphQL Schema Delegation through Declarative Programming

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, graphql-tools

I was looking at the documentation of graphql-tools, and wanted to know if we can use declarative programming model to delegate queries or mutations to sub-schemas?

https://www.graphql-tools.com/docs/schema-delegation

Specially the delegateToSchema type of call, can this done through SDL using directives?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. You can use the `@delegate` directive to delegate your query to the appropriate schema.

The sample below assumes you are querying for a customer. In your SDL, you might add:

```
type CustomerQuery
{
    customer(customerId: ID!) : Customer @delegate(schema: "CustomerServiceSchema": path: "customer(customerId: $arguments:customerId)")
}
```